# Creating a TableView with a fixed header row (does not scroll)

Tags: android

I have a TableView called aTable.
initialiseDTable() adds the first row with a RED background

**GOAL**

1. > Prevent the header row from scrolling (*WORKING FINE*)
2. > Keep the header row with the same width of each TextView which gives the feeling that it is the child of aTable (*NOT WORKING*)

**ATTEMP**

My attempt was to create a tableview before the scrollview and populate aTable then extract the header row and insert it as a child of this tableview.

**CODE TO ADD HEADER ROW TO TABLE**

```
    public void initialiseDTable() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    TableRow row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, dTable,
            false);
    View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_cell, row, false);
    TextView A = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.table_cell_text);
    A.setText(tag1);
    row.addView(v);
    v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_cell, row, false);
    A = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.table_cell_text);
    A.setText(tag2);
    row.addView(v);
    v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_cell, row, false);
    A = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.table_cell_text);
    A.setText(tag3);
    row.addView(v);
    v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_cell, row, false);
    A = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.table_cell_text);
    A.setText(tag4);
    row.addView(v);
    if (this.showEST) {
        v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_cell, row, false);
        A = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.table_cell_text);
        A.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        A.setText(tag5);
        row.addView(v);
    }
    dTable.addView(row);
}
```

**CODE**

```
public void updateATable() {
    aTable.removeAllViews();
    initialiseATable();
    for (int i = 0; i < newA.size(); i++)
        aTable.addView(newA.get(i)); //newA is an ArrayList <TableRow>
    View view = aTable.getChildAt(0);
    aTable.removeViewAt(0);
    aTableH.removeAllViews();
    aTableH.addView(view,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

**XML**

```
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/aLL">
            <TableLayout android:shrinkColumns="5"
                android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/aTableH">
            </TableLayout>
            <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/aTableSV">
                <TableLayout android:shrinkColumns="5"
                    android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/aTable">
                </TableLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

I am writing a series of blog posts which cover this precise issue. The first is [here](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/420) and describes a similar approach to the answer already given. However the next two articles cover a much more elegant solution.

Comment: I just skimmed and saw the picture seems it is still not perfect. I will read it soon.. I already implemented it my way.. You can take a look at https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.foo.beirutairport